# How to use BOOL and String

Tags: iphone

There is .plist file that has a key say XYZ and the value can be on or off.

Now I have this method `BOOL isEnabled()`.

I want to check the value for that in that plist and return BOOL based on on or off.

How do I do that?

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.BTServer.airplane.plist"];
BOOL Location = [[plistDict objectForKey:@"airplaneMode"] boolValue];

return Location;
```

This code is for Location Toggle for iPhone/SBSettings. Here for Location toggle the values are stored as 1 and 0 but for Airplane mode for which I modifying this code the values are on/off.

How do I convert on /off to BOOL?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for exactly. BOOL typed variables hold the values YES or NO (these are Objective-C keywords).

Answer (score 0):

Is the on/off encoded as a string? If so, how about a string comparison?

```
NSString *strLocation = [[plistDict objectForKey:@"airplaneMode"] lowercaseString];
if ([strLocation isEqualToString:@"on"])
{
   return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
```

Comment: With the risk of being pendantic, even though TRUE / FALSE are defined, the canonical values for BOOL types are YES / NO.

Answer (score 0):

Yo probably want to use something like this to store a BOOL value on a dictionary/plist:

```
[myDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]
```

Though you'd use YES or NO depending on the value of the integer you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do a one-line if statement like so:

```
BOOL location = ([[plistDict objectForKey:@"airplaneMode"] isEqualToString:@"On"]) ? YES : NO;
```

Comment: `YES` and `NO` are the common identifiers associated with the `BOOL` type.

Comment: TRUE, FALSE, 0 and 1 also work though, and some people understand it better.